# 2005 Pontiac Grand Am No Crank No Start No Fuel

Tags: electrical, starting

I bought my Grand Am GT 2005 a 2 months ago. It has been an excellent car up until about a week ago when intermittently, the battery would be dead when I went to start it (even if it was only shut off an hour earlier). I took it to a repair shop and they diagnosed it as a simple dead battery. So, I bought a new battery that day and the next, I swopped it out. Now up until taking the old battery out and putting the new one in, everything worked perfectly. The radio worked, I had no error codes or lights, it started on one crack. But after installing the new battery, my car won't start. I have tried numerous different things so far and non have seemed to help. When the key does into the ignition, the dadh lights up for a quick second and then all lights turn off except for Service Engine Soon. There is not flashing security. The radio only displays the time, won't turn on or tune to any stations. When I turn the key to START there is no sound. No crack, no fuel system, nothing but relays clicking. What I have also tried is jumping the starter, which when I touch the neg, and pos with a prydriver, it turns over, ignites, runs for 3 seconds, and then shuts off. I am at a complete loss. Please, I could realllllyyyyy use some insight! Regards.

Comment: security light flashing?

Comment: No, it doesn't not even come on.

Comment: do you have a scantool that will view live data? check for the engine crank request pid when the key is in the start position. is there a starter relay? or is the starter computer controlled? if there is a relay pull it and check that the computer is grounding the coil. how about the fuses? check all the underhood and in dash fuses with a multimeter.

Comment: Unfortunately I am at school for about another hour, I'll get back to you ASAP.

Comment: That said, I tried using an engine code already and it would not even connect to the ECU.

Comment: if it wouldn't connect and it did before check your fuses first make sure the pcm is getting power and ground. since you replaced the battery and now you can't connect that would be the best place to start. check the ecm a/b, ign 1/2 and other related fuses.

Comment: The other odd thing I have noticed is the wireless remote won't work. And the speakers seem to be buzzing constantly, regardless of the key being in or not.

Comment: Sometimes when you buy a used car you might be not given any relatives, like alarm remote control, or immobilizer.. it is possible that something has been deactivated, and now once you reset it, it came back on. I had this issue with my good old bug, I apparently had a alarm system on it, never seen a remote control. Found it out only when it started to yell at me..

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION: Resetting the internet computer PCM AND BCM by touching positive and negative terminals together for 1 minute! Started right up, one crank. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Could you give a but more information on your solution please?  I have a 2004 grand prix that im not able tp figure it out, I replaced the Started, BCM & Ignition switch and still haven't gotten any luck. I would like to try your solution but where exactly are the wires that I need to touch together.